# Why is iterator in set(c++) not behaving properly?

Tags: c++, iterator, set, multiset

This is code I have written:

```
multiset<int>S;
for(int i = 0;i<20;i++)
S.insert(i);
for(auto it = S.end();it!=S.begin();--it)
cout<<*it<<" ";
cout<<endl;
```

Output:

```
20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: This appears to be the correct output given your program.

Comment: It does behave properly. What did you expect? (An XY problem???)

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: I expected 19 18 17 .... 0

Comment: You're dereferencing on `S.end()`, which is UB.

Comment: You are using undefined behavior: `*S.end()`

Comment: The first time through the loop, `it` is `S.end()`, so `*it` is undefined behavior.

Comment: but there is --it which executes before everything.. @aschepler

Comment: Try using `crbegin()` and `crend()`

Comment: No, the `--it` executes at the *end* of the `for`-loop.

Comment: @user3778989 It doesn't -- `for`'s increment expression executes *after* each loop cycle.

Comment: What does S contain 20..1 or 19...0 @Chad

Comment: so you mean --it and it-- are same thing in this reference @aschepler

Comment: where is 20 coming from as i haven't inserted it @JVApen

Comment: What does S contain 20..1 or 19...0  @MTilsted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contains some undefined behavior. As you already indicated S will contain all values from 0 till 20 (exclusive), though somehow the printing gives 1 til 20 (inclusive).

Your code:

```
for(auto it = S.end();it!=S.begin();--it)
    cout<<*it<<" ";
```

The problem here is that the range `[begin, end)` has `end` referring to something which ain't part of the set. Dereferencing the iterator received from end() can crash your program or let it produce some random value. In this case, I guess you get the value 20 because of compiler optimizations. (Some black box optimization)

In C++ (and other languages), the concept of iterators is accompanied by a concept of [reverse iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator). (If you follow the link, there is a nice picture explaining the iterators.)

Basically, using the reverse iterators will allow you to loop from the back to the beginning as if you were looping with normal iterators:

```
for (auto it = S.crbegin(); it != S.crend(); ++it)
     cout << *it << " ";
```

Note that the rbegin() and crbegin() don't have any disadvantages for code complexity. (unless you want to transform them to a forward iterator again)

Bonus: By default, don't use the -- operator on iterators, it gives headaches when trying to debug.

Answer (score 1):

The loop with the iterator is incorrect and has undefined behavior because the iterator returned by the member function end() is dereferenced in the loop.

A valid program can look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main() 
{
    std::multiset<int> s;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) s.insert( i );

    for ( auto it = s.end(); it != s.begin(); ) std::cout << *--it << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Of course you could use the reverse iterator of the class returned by the function `rbegin()`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main() 
{
    std::multiset<int> s;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) s.insert( i );

    for ( auto it = s.rbegin(); it != s.rend(); ++it ) std::cout << *it << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In this case the loop looks simpler.

Comment: Congratulations for 100k rep :)

Comment: @Quentin Thanks. However this reputation does not help me to find a job in Russia.::)

Answer (score -2):

Better use:

```
for(auto it = S.rbegin(); it != S.rend(); ++it)
```

update according to comments.

Comment: so the range is S.begin() to S.end()-1 both inclusive? @BruceSun

Comment: yes, [s.begin(), s.end()) == [s.begin(), s.end()-1]

Comment: My apology for the downvote - you shouldn't iterate from `rend` to `rbegin` while incrementing.

Comment: And `std::multiset`'s iterators are bidirectional, not random access, so you can't add or subtract integers from them.